# $F$ be a finite field , then are there infinitely many polynomials $f(x) \in F[x]$ such that $f(a)=0 , \forall a \in F$ ?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field , then is it true that there are infinitely many polynomials $f(x) \in F[x]$ such that $f(a)=0 , \forall a \in F$ ?

Comment: Hint: Once you find a non-trivial one, the step to infinitely many is easy.

Comment: @AndréNicolas : $f(x)=x^n-x$ , where $n=|F|$ , is a non trivial one . Can we consider the polynomials $(f(x))^k$ then ?

Comment: $\alpha^n = \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in F$, so instead take $f(x) = x^n - x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field has $q$ elements, then $x^q-x$ works. For if $a$ is non-zero, then $a^{q-1}-1=0$. Multiplying by $x$ ensures that the polynomial is also $0$ when $a=0$.

It follows that $x^{q+k}-x^{k+1}$ also works for any positive integer $k$.